# How to convert DateTime::now() into NaiveDateTime?

Tags: datetime, rust, timestamp

I'm using Diesel and chrono. In my model I have a field of type `NaiveDateTime` which contains the `now()`. However, `NaiveDateTime` doesn't have the function `now()` or a similar one whereas `DateTime` does:

```
Utc::now()
```

How can I convert `Utc::now()` into `NaiveDateTime`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`Utc::now()` returns a `DateTime<Utc>`. You could click into the [documentation of `DateTime<T>`](https://docs.rs/chrono/*/chrono/struct.DateTime.html) and search for `NaiveDateTime`. You should find that there are two methods that will return a `NaiveDateTime`:

> `fn naive_utc(&self) -> NaiveDateTime`
>
> Returns a view to the naive UTC datetime.

> `fn naive_local(&self) -> NaiveDateTime`
>
> Returns a view to the naive local datetime.

For instance, if you need the timestamp in UTC:

```
let naive_date_time = Utc::now().naive_utc();
```

---

Note that since you are using `diesel`, you could use [`diesel::dsl::now`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/dsl/struct.now.html) instead, which will evaluate to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on the SQL side.

````
//! ```cargo
//! [dependencies]
//! diesel = { version = "1", features = ["sqlite"] }
//! ```

#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::dsl;

table! {
    posts (id) {
        id -> Integer,
        content -> Text,
        published -> Timestamp,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let conn = SqliteConnection::establish("test.db")
        .expect("Cannot open database");

    diesel::insert_into(posts::table)
        .values((
            posts::content.eq("hello"),
            posts::published.eq(dsl::now),  // <------------------
        ))
        .execute(&conn)
        .expect("Insertion failed");
}
````

Comment: +1 for pointing out that using the database as the time source is the better idea, especially in cases where you have multiple machines (with different time sources) connecting to one database.

Comment: For those who might need Local version instead - it is `Local::now().naive_local()`